# Issues with newline removal in Python

Tags: python, newline

I am currently getting information from Crunchbase in regards to the company overview. API info is available from [here](http://developer.crunchbase.com/).

In simple steps, I want to obtain name, permalink, description and overview and insert this into a MySQL db. 
To do this, I have the following code:

```
url = "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/%s.js?api_key=<insert_api_key>" %  permalink

i = 1
TIME = 5
TRYS = 3
while True:
    try:
        fh = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        cont = fh.read()
        fh.close()
        data = json.loads(cont)

    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
        print "Sleep %d seconds to try again" % (TIME * i)
        time.sleep(TIME * i)
    i += 1
    if i > TRYS:
        INVALID.append(url)
        data = None

overview = data.get("overview")
overview = strip_tags(overview).replace('\n','')
sql_data = {
    "name": data.get("name").replace('"', "'"),
    "permalink": data.get("permalink", ""),
    "description": data.get("description","").replace('\n',''),
    "overview": overview
}

keys = sql_data.keys()
#print keys
sql = """insert into %s(%s) values (""" % (TABLE, "`".join(keys))

for index, k in enumerate(keys):
    if index < len(keys)-1:
        sql += '''"%s",''' % sql_data.get(k, "")
    else: sql += sql_data.get(k,'')
        sql += """)"""
```

Please note, I will add the `strip_tags` function at the end of this code.

Anyway, I hit a stumbling block. I have attempted to strip out new lines `\n` through the use of  `.replace('\n','')` such that U do this on both `overview` and `description`. I've also tried removing all newlines by using `[\n]+`. But I still get errors on every single company. One such error is:

```
(1064, '[34816] syntax error: syntax error near "Management"\nLINE: ...agement     software.","adventnet","AdventNet",Server Management...\n                                                               ^')
3: downloading adventnet failed
```

the company overview when printing out is:

AdventNet is now Zoho ManageEngine.

```
Founded in 1996, AdventNet has served a diverse range of enterprise IT, networking and telecom customers.

AdventNet supplies server and network management software.
insert into crunchbase_overview_company(overview`permalink`name`description) values     ("AdventNet is now Zoho ManageEngine.

 Founded in 1996, AdventNet has served a diverse range of enterprise IT, networking and     telecom customers.
```

This clearly has new lines even after apparently doing something which should strip them out!

Has anyone got any advice, tips,hints to pointers as to how to deal with this issue?

**Strip tags functions:**

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    self.reset()
    self.fed = []
def handle_data(self, d):
    self.fed.append(d)
def get_data(self):
    return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
s = MLStripper()
s.feed(html)
return s.get_data()
```

Comment: Is that what you get when you `print(overview)` right after `overview = strip_tags(overview).replace('\n','')`?

Comment: I'm not understanding. Is overview "AdventNet is now Zoho ManageEngine"? Or is overview that block of output after it? The first clearly doesn't have new lines. The second does, but that's not what you stripped the new lines out of, is it?

Comment: What does strip_tags do, exactly? If I replicate this code without strip_tags, using overview.replace('\n', '') works just fine.

Comment: I do print after cleaning of tags:`overview = data.get("overview") overview  = strip_tags().replace('\n','')`
  `print overview`

Comment: Could you minimize your example and remove unrelated code? For example, if you can reproduce the issue without `urlopen()` e.g., hardcode the content that leads to the error then you should do it (remove `urllib2` related code). If you can reproduce it without `json.loads()` remove it and use a fixed `data` value. If you can remove mysql, HTMLParser code etc; do it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing carriage returns too?

```
overview = strip_tags(overview).replace('\n','').replace('\r','')
```

Often Windows adds carriage returns (\r) instead of newlines (\n).